# XCTest: how to check whether an asynchronous element exists

Tags: asynchronous, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I work on test automation for an app that communicates with the server. The app has 7 pre-defined strings. Depending on the info the server returns, which is not deterministic and depends on external factors, the app places one to three of the seven pre-defined strings in a table view as hittable static texts. The user has a choice which of those strings to tap.
To automate this test I need an asynchronous way to determine in the test code which of the 7 pre-defined strings actually appear on the screen. 
I cannot use element.exists because it takes time for static texts to appear and I do not want to call sleep() because that would slow down the test. 
So I tried to use XCTestExpectation but got a problem. XCTest always fails when waitForExpectationsWithTimeout() times out.
To illustrate the problem I wrote a simple test program:

```
func testExample() {
    let element = XCUIApplication().staticTexts["Email"]
    let gotText = haveElement(element)
    print("Got text: \(gotText)")
}

func haveElement(element: XCUIElement) -> Bool{
    var elementExists = true
    let expectation = self.expectationForPredicate(
        NSPredicate(format: "exists == true"),
        evaluatedWithObject: element,
        handler: nil)
    self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(NSTimeInterval(5))  { error in
        elementExists = error == nil
    }
    return elementExists
}
```

The test always fails with

```
Assertion Failure: Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 5 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "Expect predicate `exists == 1` for object "Email" StaticText".
```

I also tried

```
func haveElement(element: XCUIElement) -> Bool {
    var elementExists = false
    let actionExpectation = self.expectationWithDescription("Expected element")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        while true {
            if element.exists {
                actionExpectation.fulfill()
                elementExists = true
                break
            } else {
                sleep(1)
            }
        }
    }
    self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(NSTimeInterval(5))  { error in
        elementExists = error == nil
        }
    return elementExists
}
```

In this case the test always fails with

```
Stall on main thread.
```

error.
So the question is how do I check a presence of an asynchronous UI element that may or may not appear within specified time without the test failing on timeout?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating the test. If you're communicating with a server, there is unnecessary variability in your tests -- my suggestion is to use stubbed network data for each case.

You can get a brief introduction to stubbing network data here:
http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-stub-network-data/

You will eliminate the randomness in the test based on response time of the server as well as the randomness of which string is appearing. Create test cases that respond to each case (i.e, how the app responds when you tap on each individual string)

Comment: Sorry, stabbing does not work in my case because there were bugs in the app that manifest not only under some permutations of these 7 strings but also the choices made before and after. The total number of permutations is too big to create test cases for each.

Comment: The real question is why waitForExpectationsWithTimeout throws when expectation times out. Is there a way to prevent that and to let the test code to handle timeout in a way other than XCTAssert? There are cases when server timeout means that a repeat request to the server with different parameters is in order rather than to just abort the case. I cannot set continueAfterFailure = true because in most other cases the test should fail at XCTAssert.